# CLI for todo App - help debugging current solution using Commander or change approach to Readline and Event Emitter?

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-line-interface, readline, node-commander

I am trying to build a CLI for a node js only todo app using commander and conf modules in node js, with chalk to colour the output . I am not sure how to resolve the errors being returned:

ReferenceError: require is not defined in ES module scope, you can use import instead
This file is being treated as an ES module because it has a '.js' file extension
contains "type": "module". To treat it as a CommonJS script, rename it to use the '.cjs' file extension.

I'm getting the above error for both conf and commander

Any suggestions on how I could go about debugging this, or changing approach to using readline and events/EventEmitter would be better, will be appreciated, Thanks

Below is a REDACTED version of code:

list.js

```
const conf = new (require('conf'))();
const chalk = require('chalk');

function list() {
  const todoList = conf.get('todo-list');
  if (todoList && todoList.length) {
    console.log(
      chalk.blue.bold(
        'Tasks in green are done. Tasks in yellow are still not done.'
      )  
     }
    }

module.exports = list;
```

index.js file

```
const { program } = require('commander');
const list = require('./list');
program.command('list').description('List all the TODO tasks').action(list);
program.command('add <task>').description('Add a new TODO task').action(add);
program.parse();
```

package.json file

```
{
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "keywords": [],
  "dependencies": {
    "chalk": "^5.0.0",
    "chalk-cli": "^5.0.0",
    "commander": "^8.3.0",
    "conf": "^10.1.1"
  },
  "bin": {
    "todos": "index.js"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `package.json` you have:

```
"type": "module",
```

This means files with the `.js` suffix are assumed to be ECMAScript rather than CommonJS. If you want to use CommonJS you can change the file suffix or change the `"type"` property.

Or you can use the new syntax. In ECMAScript you use `import`, in CommonJS you use `require`.

To read more about "type" see: https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/packages.html#determining-module-system

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to post an answer. I did my own research into this before reading your response and have posted my own answer. However I will accept this response as the accepted answer because this would have lead me to the answer I have posted.

Answer (score 0):

After some more research I found out I was 'muddying the waters' between CJS or ESM modules.
CJS modules use require and that is the old way of doing things prior to ES6 modules
ESM modules use import

My package.json says type: module telling NodeJS that I am using ESM. But the code is saying CJS.

These are the steps I take to fix this:

- rename index.js to index.mjs
- update package.json accordingly
- replace all  require calls with import statements
- replace module.exports = list with default export = list (or used a named export)